# Stop executing code and wait for a button to be clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I've design my app in such way that the "error" screen is a Control which I am showing on top of any other controls.

```
public Alert(Control control,string message, Stages stage)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            control.Controls.Add(this);
            Size = new Size(579, 524);
        }

        public static void Show(Control control,string message, Stages stage)
        {
            new Alert(control, message, stage).Show();
        }
```

However, when the error screen is showed the code continues to execute and I don't want that. I don't want to use a Form instead of a Control to use the .ShowDialog() functionality. The error screen has a button which when clicked should resume the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by "code continues to execute"? ... that other controls and windows still react to input or can get focused? (so ... you want some kind of modal dialog without a dialog?)

Comment: Why not create the Alert as a Form and use "ShowDialog"? That's it's intended usage.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing isn't very standard, so there's no quick and easy way. You pretty much just have to disable everything else.

```
public static void Show(Control control,string message, Stages stage)
{
    new Alert(control, message, stage).Show();
    var otherControls = control.Parent.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where( x => x != control).ToList();
    foreach (var c in otherControls)
    {
        c.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

And then of course you'd have to re-enable them afterward, taking care of course not to re-enable controls that weren't enabled to begin with.

A more common solution would be to just show the error message at the top without disabling anything else. This is easier for the end user because they can continue working without that extra click. But if you truly want to block the user, a dialog box is the standard way.